# impossible to insert in sql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-insert

My problem is simple but i don't find solution
I can insert into database with safari, opera and chrome but impossible to insert something within internet explorer and firefox
Some help will be appreciated

```
if (isset($_SESSION['pseudo']) && isset($_SESSION['pass'])){ // people connected or not 
if(mysql_result($res,0)==0 ) {// if key doesn't appear in database, show add button
?>

<form method="post" action="">
<input type="image" src="../../images/favoris.png" name="insert" class="insert" value="insert">
</form> 

<?php
}else{ ?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="image" src="../../images/delete.png" name="delete" class="delete" value="delete">
</form> 
<?php
} 
}
if (isset($_POST['insert']) ) // if button add is clicked, all informations will be add in database
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO favoris (id, client, profil, photo, prenom, reference, age, lien) VALUES('','$pseudo' ,'$pseudo$referenceBase','$photoBase','$prenomBase', '$referenceBase', '$ageBase','$lienBase')";
mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL ! '.$sql.'<br>.mysql_error());
echo '<p style= "position: absolute; color: #b9121b; margin-left: 170px; margin-top: 366px"> Profil added!</p>  
<script type="text/javascript"> window.setTimeout("location=(\'\');",1000) </script>';}
else{
'<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">document.location.href="../../index.php"</SCRIPT>';
  }
```

Comment: PHP runs on the server, the browser doesn't make a difference.

Comment: You have a missing ' here: `mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL ! '.$sql.'<br>.mysql_error());`, just a warning.

Comment: Wide open to SQL injection (`mysql`?).

Comment: mysql_query ?? Why ?

Comment: I put ' missing but nothing change. Thanks